# ArgumentException while reordering listViewItems

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to reorder `listView` items with a mouse and I'm getting this mysterious `Parameter is not valid ArgumentException` either when I'm starting to drag or when I'm dropping item. There are no other details, no stack trace. Crashes entire app.

It works fine when I'm reordering `ObservableCollection<string>` but keeps crashing on `ObservableCollection<MyControl>`

`MyControl` is just a simple `UserControl` with a `TextBlock` inside.

I tried `CollectionViewSource` approach and it's the same.

Any ideas?

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="App3.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App3"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" CanReorderItems="True" AllowDrop="True"/>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
namespace App3
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private MainPageViewModel mainPageViewModel;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            mainPageViewModel = new MainPageViewModel();

            DataContext = mainPageViewModel;

            //  THIS IS NOT WORKING
            MyControl myControl1 = new MyControl("Hello1");
            MyControl myControl2 = new MyControl("Hello2");
            MyControl myControl3 = new MyControl("Hello3");

            mainPageViewModel.Items.Add(myControl1);
            mainPageViewModel.Items.Add(myControl2);
            mainPageViewModel.Items.Add(myControl3);

            //  THIS IS WORKING
            //string s1 = "h1";
            //string s2 = "h2";
            //string s3 = "h3";

            //mainPageViewModel.Items.Add(s1);
            //mainPageViewModel.Items.Add(s2);
            //mainPageViewModel.Items.Add(s3);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace App3
{
    public class MainPageViewModel : BaseModel
    {
        //  THIS IS NOT WORKING
        private ObservableCollection<MyControl> items = new ObservableCollection<MyControl>();
        public ObservableCollection<MyControl> Items
        {
            get { return items; }
            set
            {
                items = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        //  THIS IS WORKING
        //private ObservableCollection<string> items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        //public ObservableCollection<string> Items
        //{
        //    get { return items; }
        //    set
        //    {
        //        items = value;
        //        OnPropertyChanged();
        //    }
        //}
    }
}
```

**MyControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="App3.MyControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App3"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <TextBlock Name="tb"/>
</UserControl>
```

**MyControl.cs**

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
namespace App3
{
    public sealed partial class MyControl : UserControl
    {
        public MyControl(string sName)
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            tb.Text = sName;
        }
    }
}
```

**BaseModel.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace App3
{
    public class BaseModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string name = "")
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Looks like there's also no problem with reordering simple objects, so I guess there is something wrong with reordering `UserControl`.

```
namespace App3
{
    public class SampleClass
    {
        private string sName;
        public SampleClass(string sName)
        {
            this.sName = sName;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return sName;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT 2**

Reordering objects that derive from `CheckBox` crashes exactly like `MyControl`.

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App3
{
    public class MyCheckBox : CheckBox
    {
        public MyCheckBox(string sName)
        {
            Content = sName;
        }
    }
}
```

Same for standard checkBoxes

```
CheckBox checkBox1 = new CheckBox() { Content = "hello1" };
CheckBox checkBox2 = new CheckBox() { Content = "hello2" };
CheckBox checkBox3 = new CheckBox() { Content = "hello3" };

mainPageViewModel.Items.Add(checkBox1);
mainPageViewModel.Items.Add(checkBox2);
mainPageViewModel.Items.Add(checkBox3);
```

---

**EDIT 3**

Seems like the only solution is to use simple class for holding data

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App3
{
    public class MyCheckBox : BaseModel
    {
        private string sName;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return sName; }
            set
            {
                sName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MyCheckBox(string sName)
        {
            Name = sName;
        }
    }
}
```

and `DataTemplate` for `ListViewItem` to display it

```
<Page
    x:Class="App3.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App3"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" CanReorderItems="True" AllowDrop="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Page>
```

instead of adding `UserControl` directly to `ListView` items.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the reordering of Visuals is not supported entirely. When reorganizing items in a listview, a lot happens underneath, as for example dynamically creating and destroying containers that hold your content, etc.

In order to display the resorted element, some items need to be appended elsewhere in the visual tree. 
The drag/drop tries to attach an already attached Visual (your UserControl) which might cause the exception - a Visual can not be attached to multiple parents.

Your approach of using POCOs / ViewModels with Datatemplates should be sufficient to get the work done, as the de- and attach semantics are considered by ListView already.

There should be more exception details, though.